# getting data from database with PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I've a issue and i just can't figure out what the problem is, there is obviously something that i overlook. See the following code.

```
<?php
class CompanyContact
{

    //fields;
    private $iID;
    private $sFirstName;
    private $sInfix;
    private $sLastName;
    private $sPhoneNumber;
    private $sEmail;

    private $dbCon;

    public function __construct(){


        $sQuery = "SELECT * FROM company_contact";
        $this->dbCon = Registry::get('oDb')->prepare($sQuery);
        $this->dbCon->execute();


        $data = $this->dbCon->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($data);
        echo "</pre>";

        $this->iID = $data['id'];

    }

    public function getFirstName(){
        return $this->sFirstName;
    }


}
```

when i print the $data i see output. But the problem is when i want to output the id of a user. Then i get the following error: Notice: Undefined index: id

in my controller I've the following code:

```
<?php 
$c = new CompanyContact();
$oTemplate->assign("contacts",$c);
?>
```

in my view i want to have this

```
<?php
  foreach($this->var['contacts'] as $contacts){
  echo $contacts->getFirstName();
}
?>
```

And i know that isn't the best intention to have PHP in your view but I'm working with the MVC framework that my company made by them selves so it's kinda crap. Thank in advance.

Comment: please provide the print the $data;

Comment: @DinoBabu this my $data output.

[0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [first_name] => Navid
            [infix] => 
            [last_name] => Mirzaie Milani
            [phone_number] => 06-42743326
            [email] => navid.ncreative@gmail.com
            [password] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [first_name] => Geert
            [infix] => de
            [last_name] => Haan
            [phone_number] => 015-1234567
            [email] => geert.de.haan@upcmail.nl
            [password] => 
        )

)

Comment: @Navid As you can see in the output, there is no `$data['id']`. `$data` is an array of rows and each has an 'id' field. Please read the answer of @Dino-babu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's multidimensional array, since `$this->dbCon->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` will return *all rows*.

$this->iID = $data[0]['id'];

Comment: ooh damn that is very very stupid of me... thank you very much, the only problem is now that i can't see anything in my view. while when i'm outputting the data in the model i get output back.

Answer (score 1):

to get only the first id

```
$this->iID = $data[0]['id'];
```

for all

```
foreach($data as $d) {
 echo $d['id']
}
```

Comment: i understand that the $data[0]['id'] is only one field of the whole row of my data array. But when i want to loop trough them in my view it doesn't output anything. 

Controller: 

$c = new CompanyContact();
$oTemplate->assign("aContacts",$c);

View:
<?php
foreach($this->var['aContacts'] as $oContacts){
 echo $oContacts->getFirstName();
}
?>

Comment: @Navid you don't set your firstname anywhere, it is null.